# Labeling from X/Y Coordinate in ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, labeling

[image]

Here I have a point at the line with an X/Y coordinate.  It also has a leader line to it.  This leader line has an X2/Y2 coordinate.  Both of these coordinates are in the same attribute table.  Then, I have another attribute "A".  The fields in "A" are different numbers.  Each point maybe have a similar or different number. 
I would like the to have the label "A" displayed from the X2/Y2 coordinate.

I don't have much experience with VBScript or Python.

Within my attributes, I have an X and Y coordinate.  I would like to turn on a label from these coordinates.  The unique part is that these coordinates were created from a leader line of the original symbol.  We now want to put the label within the symbol.  The new X/Y coordinates are the exact center of where to do this.

The attributes I would like to use are A, X, and Y.

Comment: Can you use the labeling feature within ArcMap? It could put labels of one field, based on the X, Ys of the feature. Go Vols!

Comment: Hello!  Thank you for replying.  I could but within my attributes I have two separate X/Y Coordinates.  One is for the actual point and the other is for the new point created from the leader line.  I would like to use the X/Y Coordinate from the leader line.

Comment: Try exporting those features with the field of X/Y's that you don't need turned off, then labeling

Comment: Yea that was what I was thinking too, but as a last option.  It seems like I might have to do that.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not able to follow what you are trying to describe.  Would you be able to [edit] your question to include a picture and more words of explanation about precisely what you have in your attribute table and what you want to see on your map, please?

Comment: I updated my question.  I hope it helps clarify it a little bit.